# How to display different pages in iframes for different time intervals dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have 2 Iframes having the ids `demo` and `demo1`. 
I have a list of 5 html files (promo1,promo2,promo3,promo4,promo5) which have to be displayed in both Iframes, one after the other, repeatedly. 
Each html page has a different time intervals for which it should be displayed in the frame

Here is my JavaScript code in which the `dict` represents each html and the time for which it should be displayed.

the following code makes the browser crash and fill up the memory. i know its because of the reccurrsion. please help me

```
;(function($){

"use strict";

var index=1,
  dict={"promo1":70000,"promo2":46500,"promo3":18000,"promo4":93000,"promo5":86000},

var $firstFrame = $("#demo"),
  $secondFrame = $("#demo1");

$(function (){

  function demo(frameId,index){

    frameId.attr("src","static/promo" + index + ".html");
    frameId.load(function(){
      if(a){

        a.clearTimeout();
      }
      if(index < 5){

        a = setTimeout(demo(frameId , index + 1),dict["promo"+index]);
      }
      else if(index = 5){
        var a = setTimeout(demo(frameId , 1),dict["promo"+index]);
      }

    });
    index += 1;

      if(index > 5){

        index = 1;
      }

 }
 demo($firstFrame , 1);
 });
}(window.jQuery));
```

Comment: Try use `setTimeout`  instead of `setInterval`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per @fuyushimoya 's comment, you need to use [setTimeOut](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout) instead of [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval).

setTimeOut:

> Calls a function or executes a code snippet after a specified delay.

setInterval:

> Calls a function or executes a code snippet repeatedly, with a fixed
>   time delay between each call to that function. Returns an intervalID.

In other words, setTimeOut calls a function **once after the timeout** expires, setInterval calls a function an **unlimited amount of times, at an interval**.

You should be good to go by just changing that function.

Answer (score 0):

**Before**

```
$demo.attr("src","static/display" + index + ".html");
$demo1.attr("src","static/display" + index + ".html");
```

**After**

```
$demo.attr("src","static/display" + index + ".html?" + Math.random());
$demo1.attr("src","static/display" + index + ".html?" + Math.random());
```

Comment: That is only to handle caching. It is not answering the question

Answer (score 0):

Use setTimeout rather than setInterval. setInterval causes the demo() function to be invoked in repeated time intervals and setTimeout invoke the demo() function only once and it is the required behavior.